# extract XML nested contents using XPATH java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

im trying to extract xml nested contents for my dependencies tag in my pom.
But it is  not getting the correct dependenices tag eventhough the location is specified. any help?
This is my pom.xml

```
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    
    
    <build>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intent.tm</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Compress JS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPSJca</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

this is my code

```
private static String nodeToString(Node node) throws TransformerException {
        StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
        Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        xform.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(buf));
        return (buf.toString());
    

}

File fXmlFile = new File(prop.getProperty("testFile"));
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document;
        Node result = null;
       
            document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(fXmlFile);
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String xpathStr = "//project//dependencies";
            result = (Node) xPath.evaluate(xpathStr, document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            log.info(nodeToString(result));
```

Actual output:

```
<dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
```

Expected output:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intent.tm</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Compress JS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPSJca</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

For some reason it is printing the dependencies in the build tag when the location specified is not build..im confused why this is happening and is there anyway to get my expected out?

Comment: xPath.evaluate(xpathStr, document, XPathConstants.NODE); returns one node. evaluate(xpathStr, document, XPathConstants.NODESET) would return a list of nodes. // matches anything under, so you're asking for dependencies everywhere under project, not just in the children, but also grandchildren.

Comment: @JPMoresmau so what should be modified to achieve this? can u paste the whole code in answer

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Node i get this when i change to NODESET

Comment: Sorry, ignore that suggestion

Comment: @JP Moresmau can u pls loook at this issue im facing regarding xpath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361493/trying-to-use-replace-to-replace-xml-dependencies-extracted-by-using-xpath-ja#

Answer (score 2):

In XPath `//` can match any number of subpaths, so it finds dependencies inside the build section too. If I change your code to say

```
 String xpathStr = "/project/dependencies";
```

I get the output you wanted. One slash is to match exactly one level in the XML, so we get project from the root, then dependencies straight under project.

Comment: thank you soo much i did nt know we could do with /

Comment: im having trouble with doing.replace() for the result im getting which contains the  extracted depededncies.. im planning to relplace the text with some other dependency but not able to do so... any hepl?