# Trying to use .replace() to replace XML dependencies extracted by using XPATH java

Tags: java, xpath, replace, xml-parsing, contains

i have a pom xml and pom-web xml.
im trying to copy the dependency from pom-web to pom.xml by extracting the dependency into a variable using **Xpath** and trying to do .replace in the pom.xml file with the variable. but im not able to replace the content via the variable as the **if condition for .contains() is false**. Any help below is the code i used

pom.xml

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.tm</groupId>
            <artifactId>gameJdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Compress JS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPSJca</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPS</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom-web.xml

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com</groupId>
            <artifactId>passwordsdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Compress JS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPSJca</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPS</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tesdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Expected pom.xml output after replace:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com</groupId>
            <artifactId>passwordsdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Compress JS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPSJca</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPS</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tesdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my code for extracting the Dependency using using xpath

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public static void main (String args[]){
        





 Path c1=Paths.get(prop.getProperty("testPom"));
            Path c2=Paths.get(prop.getProperty("testPomweb"));
            //String pom = readFile(CfoServerModifications.class.getResourceAsStream(prop.getProperty("testPom")));
            //String web = readFile(CfoServerModifications.class.getResourceAsStream(prop.getProperty("testPomweb")));            
            String pomFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(c1),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String pomWeb = new String(Files.readAllBytes(c2),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            Document doc_web = Jsoup.parse(pomWeb,"",Parser.xmlParser());
            Document doc_pom = Jsoup.parse(pomFile,"",Parser.xmlParser());
            doc_pom.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
            doc_web.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
           // System.out.println(doc_pom.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
            Elements dependencies_web = doc_web.select("project>dependencies");
            Elements dependencies_pom = doc_pom.select("project>dependencies");
            //log.info(dependencies_web.toString());
            // remove the old dependencies
            dependencies_pom.clear();
            //log.info("pom clear"+dependencies_pom.toString());
            //add the new dependencies
            dependencies_pom.addAll(dependencies_web);
            //log.info("pom web added to pom "+dependencies_pom.toString());
           
            Files.write(Paths.get(prop.getProperty("dummyfile")),doc_pom.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: @firephil i have updated the code with what u asked for...im not sure the above answers my question im trying to replace the existing node using the contains and .replace with the new node into the file outlined in the expected result

Comment: maybe some more import required but u should be able to do a quick fix when hover over them

Comment: Don't try to process lexical (serialized) XML with regular expressions: do an XSLT transformation.

Comment: @Michael Kay can u pls provide code answer to the above question i feel like you are trying to move away from the original question

Comment: I have been stuck with this issue for a week i would love to get this sorted today pls help me achive the expected result

Comment: @Davertonator I'm not going to help you get your design working because I think it's an incorrect design. I don't think the XSLT solution is at all difficult, but to show you any code I would need to reverse-engineer the requirements from your non-working solution, and that's a big ask, especially on a public holiday.

Comment: @firephil pls check  the below i cant resolve the issue i got the JSOUP depedency but gettting error with file.writeString and .readAllBytes in the ReadFile() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) which can parse xml easily and not reinvent the wheel.

Read each xml file to memory, copy the dependencies node from one xml and replace them with the other's.

Here is a working example :

```
package replacexmlnode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class ReplaceXmlNode {
    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    String pom = readFile(ReplaceNode.class.getResourceAsStream("pom-plain.xml"));
    String web = readFile(ReplaceNode.class.getResourceAsStream("pom-web.xml"));
    
    Document doc_web = Jsoup.parse(web,"",Parser.xmlParser());
    Document doc_pom = Jsoup.parse(pom,"",Parser.xmlParser());
    
    Elements dependencies_web = doc_web.select("project>dependencies");

    //remove old dependencies        
    doc_pom.select("project>dependencies").remove();

    // add new dependencies
    doc_pom.select("project").first().appendChild(dependencies_web.first());       
    
    doc_pom.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    Files.write(Paths.get("pom-plain_out.xml"), doc_pom.toString().getBytes());
 }

  public static String readFile(InputStream in) throws IOException{
   
    return new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 }
}
```

**If you use maven get Jsoup depency from** [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.13.1)

Comment: this ddoesnt work as ur getting this elements by tags and it is taking unwanted depeencies tag ...thats why i used xpath to get the specific dependecies tag under project level...with the above code it takes all the depedencies tags in the xml which is not whati i want

Comment: if u look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355118/extract-xml-nested-contents-using-xpath-java this is the issue where it is picking up multiple depedencies tag..when i want specific dependencies tag

Comment: see im still gettting output like this </groupId> 
  <artifactId>
   p6spy
  </artifactId> 
  <version>
   3.7.0
  </version> which is split line by line...is there anyway u can make it like<version>1.3</version> like this in one line? right now all the elements are split line by line which messes up my existing xml document

Comment: check the Question i have put the Jsoup output for u to see

Comment: one question could u update this  in ur answer as its available for everyone to see
i see this when i print org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings@2437c6dc -->   System.out.println(doc_pom.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false));

Comment: also when i wrote to file i realise that the pom web depedencies didnt get copied over to pom? is this working for u

Comment: when i wrote the contents it was the same content that was present in pom file eventhough the systemout.pritnln(dependencies_pom.toString()) prints out the correct dependencies

Comment: i did to another file also for debugging but its printing out same content as it was not pom_web dependencies..i will change the questoin with my code i have so u can check...as im not using some of ur method readLine() as im on java8

Comment: property files are just to load the file path as it is defined in config file nothing else..im wondering if i go java 6 that might cause my other code to break i think

Comment: the issue is Files.write(Paths.get(prop.getProperty("dummyfile")),doc_pom.toString().getBytes()); this not having the copied over contents

Comment: i printed out System.out.println(doc_pom.toString()); this doesnt have the copied over contents, this doesnt not get updated by the code u have used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231902/discussion-between-firephil-and-davertonator).